# Will celery handle tasks gracefully if supervisorctl stop/start/restart is used?

Tags: celery, supervisord

In a case recently, I had to restart some inexplicably idle workers run by supervisord. We are thinking about adding a periodic restart, say, once or twice a day.

This could easily be done using supervisorctl, but is there any chance tasks will be lost while the restart occurs?

Comment: Did you get the solution? I have similar need :)